# Using generic types for name spacing in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, namespaces

### My Namespacing Pattern in Swift

I often nest types like structs or classes for namespacing in Swift.

For example, I might have a `SettingsView` struct that is composed from several other views:

- `PushNotificationSettingsView`
- `AppearanceSettingsView`
- `UserSettingsView`

In this case, I would nest the component views inside an extension on `SettingsView` and rename them like this:

```
extension SettingsView {
    struct PushNotifications: View { ... }
    struct Appearance: View { ... }
    struct User: View { ... }
}
```

With these nested types, I can make the main `SettingsView` much more readable:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SettingsView.PushNotifications()
            SettingsView.Appearance()
            SettingsView.User()
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `SettingsView`, we're also inside the same namespace, so we can even omit all the `SettingsView.` prefixes and it simplifies to this:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PushNotifications()
            Appearance()
            User()
        }
    }
}
```

I find this code extremely readable and desirable. When I want to reference any of these components views from outside the `SettingsView`, I'll have to use the `SettingsView.` prefix as shown in the example above. (I find it also a bit cleaner to use `SettingsView.Appearance` rather than `AppearanceSettingsView` as it visualizes the hierarchy and indicates that `Appearance` is a subview-component of `SettingsView`.)

---

### ⚡️ The Problem with Generics

This pattern has served me well in many occasions, but it breaks down the moment you give a view a generic parameter. That's necessary in many situations. A typical example is when I want to use a view model that I can mock for testing:

```
struct SettingsView<M: SettingsViewModel>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: M
    // ...
}
```

If I now want to reference any of the component views from outside the `SettingsView`, I can't do this anymore:

```
SettingsView.Appearance()
```

because the type is incomplete without specifying the generic parameter `M`. I need to put something in the angle brackets like this:

```
SettingsView<MyConcreteSettingsViewModel>.Appearance()
```

Obviously, this doesn't make any sense because in this case, the type of the view model has no relevance at all as I only use the `SettingsView` as a namespace. I could fill in any concrete type that conforms to `SettingsViewModel`. It makes the code much harder to read and when I first read such code as a developer, I'll ask myself what the meaning of this generic type is. That's a bad practice in my opinion.

---

### ❓ So here's my question:

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Can I somehow use Swift types for namespacing as shown above without running into a problem as soon as I add a generic parameter to the type?

(One obvious solution is to implement a convention to never use types for namespacing that can also be instantiated, but this seems like too big a price to pay.)

Comment: Dependency injection, Your view has no business knowing if you are running mocks or testing.

Comment: Can you elaborate? From my point of view, injecting a generic view model is just that → dependency injection.

Comment: You do it at a lower level, https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/

Comment: I think the referenced post solves a slightly different problem. It's about dependency injection in terms of broader things like network managers or data stores. In this question, I'm injecting a view model. Our general concept is that each view has a dedicated view model that might be initialized with data from a previous view's view model. I don't think it's a practical pattern to have a single `InjectedValues` that holds _all_ of the app's view models.

Comment: Another problem is that Antoine's approach makes use of existentials. It would now throw warnings in the latest Xcode version (in the future, it will be an error) and would require us to declare the properties with `any` in their type. This is discouraged as it will have a bad impact on performance because the actual type can only be resolved at runtime.

Comment: What are you doing in your view models that isn’t the “broader” stuff? View state management should be handled in structs. The link’s setup doesn’t cause any errors or warnings if some property, if you start mixing SwiftUI into it of course it will because SwiftUI requires concretes. There is no reason to have a giant list of view models. Having classes with concurrency will be a nightmare with Swift6.

Comment: Also, ViewModels should technically never know about each other, they should never share data. Anywhere you read about MVVM you will see this.